# Disabled textbox editable in IE8

Tags: asp.net, textbox, internet-explorer-8

I am developing my app in asp.net web forms. The textbox is set like this

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server" Enabled="false" ></asp:TextBox>
```

and this is the corresponding HTML markup

```
<input name="txt1" type="text" value="1.0" id="txt1" disabled="disabled" />
```

It is not editable upto this point.

I enable Caret browsing in IE8 (press F7) and then this field becomes editable, though the text is grayed out and consequently gives a  wrong feeling to the user that the field is editable. This does not happen if I mark the textbox as readonly, but I do not want to mark it as a readonly field. Any suggestions on how to have the textbox in disabled mode when in Caret Browsing.

Edit1: I am not looking for a solution which would change IE settings/registry, am looking for a programmatic solution as my site is a public facing website

Edit2: View states are enabled for the page and for the controls

Comment: Why do you not want to use readonly if that solves the problem?

Comment: we have some existing code, changing it to readonly would mean that we would have to change it in other places too

Comment: I don't see what affect setting an already disabled textbox to readonly would have that you would need to make other changes.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but thanks for reporting this, I was going crazy trying to figure out how one of the customers was able to do that. Here is the jQuery snippet I used to fix this `if ($.browser.msie) {$('input[disabled=disabled]').attr('readonly', 'readonly');}`

Answer (score 0):

I can get you started quickly with this script:

```
<script> document.onkeyup = KeyCheck; 


function KeyCheck() {   alert(document.getElementById("txt1").value); }  </script> </script>
```

Put this all the way on top of the html.
Now you get hold of the keypress.
When in caret mode, IE seems to ignore the text's javascript events

Comment: Is this a solution ?you are just showing the textbox value on the `onkeyup` event. How does it prevent me from altering the textbox value ?

Comment: See my second answer.
I had given you a hint for handling this scenario in first answer.
Thanks for the -ve marking!

Answer (score 0):

Alright. I gave you a Hint to build up on. (Thanks for the -1)
Here is the HTML code that you are looking for. Make sure to populate the initialVal using ASP code.

```
<script>
document.onkeyup = KeyCheck;       
var initialVal="1.0"

function KeyCheck()
{
    if(document.getElementById("txt1").value != initialVal) {
        document.getElementById("txt1").value = initialVal;
        return false;
    }
}   
</script>

<input name="txt1" type="text" value="1.0" id="txt1" disabled="disabled" />
```